# Is it possible to initialize an empty default value on leftOuterJoin?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two following rdds:

```
name_to_hour = sc.parallelize([("Amy", [7,8,7,18,19]), ("Dan", [6,7]), ("Emily", [1,2,3,7,7,7,2])])

name_biz = sc.parallelize(["Amy", "Brian", "Chris", "Dan", "Emily"])
```

and I want to join them, so my resulting rdd looks like this:

```
[('Amy', [7, 8, 7, 18, 19]), ('Chris', []), ('Brian', []), ('Dan', [6, 7]), ('Emily', [1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7, 2])]
```

I can achieve that with what I think is a clumsy solution:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

name_to_hour = sc.parallelize([("Amy", [7,8,7,18,19]), ("Dan", [6,7]), ("Emily", [1,2,3,7,7,7,2])])

name_biz = sc.parallelize(["Amy", "Brian", "Chris", "Dan", "Emily"])

temp = name_biz.map(lambda x: (x, []))

joined_rdd = temp.leftOuterJoin(name_to_hour)

def concat(my_tup):
    if my_tup[1] is None:
        return []
    else:
        return my_tup[1]

result_rdd = joined_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], concat(x[1])))

print "\033[0;34m{}\033[0m".format(result_rdd.collect())
```

Is there a better way to do it?

I was thinking that if it was possible to somehow specify on the `leftOuterJoin`, that non-empty fields keep what they had in `name_to_hour` and empty get default value of `[]`, the my problem could be solved much more easily, but I don't think there is such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can approach this problem is to leverage lexicographical ordering of Python lists. Since empty list is always "less than" non empty one we can simply make an `union` and reduce with `max`:

```
temp.union(name_to_hour).reduceByKey(max)
```

This of course assumes that the keys are unique.